# Can I pass my generics in template in VueJS TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics, quasar-framework

I have some abstraction in VueJS like this

```
<script lang="ts">
  function init<T extends boolean | string >(arr: Array<T>): ReturnType<(arr: Array<T>) => boolean> {
    // execute the code
  }
</script>
```

and how do I pass the generics in the templates?

```
<template>
  <my-component :init="init<MyGenerics>(someArray)" />
</template>
```

is it possible?

Comment: What will you gain from this in template? Just go with "init(someArray)"`

Comment: @AlekseyL. the params has own generics types and I just want to work with it.